# How to Submit a search query

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I'm trying to make an AutoHotkey script that basically copies the selected text and opens a webpage in chrome with the search results. This webpage is a company website and you need login privileges so I can't really share it with you guys. However when I inspect the website I cant really find a way to make the search happen.

The "Submit Search button" doesn't seem to have a hyperlink that it links to that I could modify

```
<tr class="ez1">
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" onclick="clearSession();"
                    value="Submit"
                    class="Button" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="submit"
                    value="Cancel"
                    class="Button" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am currently making it work using "tabs" (so basically open website, input tab 24 times to highlight field, paste clipboard, input tab 3 times to highlight submit button and then input enter).

However, I don't feel this is the most appropriate way and I was wondering how to find the "URL" that the submit button redirects to.

Comment: As long as the page is static (not delivered by AJAX or other live CMS), you have access to the page elements in Internet Explorer using the DOM and ordinary js selectors (e.g., wb.Document.getElementByID("Your_Element_ID").click(); or wb.Document.getElementsByClassName("Your_Element_Class")[0].click() etc.)

Comment: I use Chrome.However I have microsoft Edge. And I tried using a script and just doing the getelementbyid().click() but it doesnt seem to do anything (I doesnt select the id given).

Comment: Firstly, it ONLY works in IE.  Secondly, you have to create the IE object using wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application") or search through open windows in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows() to find the right one using wb.LocationName.  Thirdly, you have to make it visible using wb.Visible := true.  Then, only if the page is revealed to the DOM, you can use the selectors.  See https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/47052-basic-webpage-controls-with-javascript-com-tutorial/